# Added error in blockquote

Tags: php, sql

I have an `sql request` to search dynamically the name of my customer from my `database`:

```
 $input = strtolower( $_GET['input'] );
 $len = strlen($input);
 $aResults = array();

        if ($len)
        {

        $aUsers="'Select * From `clients` Where `clients`.`Libelle` LIKE '" . %$input% . "'";
        $aResults[] = array( "id"=>($i+1) ,"value"=>htmlspecialchars($aUsers[$i]); 
}
```

it returns an error:

> Parse unexpected %
>   Can someone please tell me where is my fault ?
>   Thank you.

Comment: Try `LIKE '%$input%' ` instead of `LIKE '" . %$input% . "'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error in your SQL statement, you need to change below SQL:

```
$aUsers="'Select * From `clients` Where `clients`.`Libelle` LIKE '" . %$input% . "'";
```

to

```
$aUsers="'Select * From `clients` Where `clients`.`Libelle` LIKE '%" . $input . "%'";
```